# How to use multiple tools in one Gitlab CI job without custom docker images?

Tags: bash, docker, gitlab-ci

I have a couple of Gitlab CI jobs that use multiple cli tools. For example I might need to use java, nodejs, python, docker and git in the same job. This means I have two options:

1. Use one of the official images (`node`, `openjdk`, `python`, `docker:dind`, `git`) and download+install the other tools in the container every time the job runs.

   - I don't like this because the process of downloading and installing these tools is really redundant, slow and a waste of resources.
2. Create a custom image based on one of the official images and install the other tools in the image.

   - I don't like this because maintaining such a custom image takes a lot of time and effort especially if you want to keep everything at the latest version and it gets worse and worse the more tools you try to jam into a single image. Stability can also be an issue because some tools prefer running on an Ubuntu-based image and others might prefer an alpine base image.

Ideally, there would be a way to use multiple docker images in the same job that share a volume and arbitrarily run commands in the context of any container you want.

I know that I can specify service images on a job like this:

```
my_job:
  image: node:latest
  script:
    - echo "Hello World"
  services:
    - name: mysql:latest
      alias: mysql
    - name: redis:latest
      alias: redis
```

and then access them over the network, addressing them by using the alias as the domain.
But that wouldn't be of much help in case of an official image like `node` because these images don't host any network services.

Any ideas how this can be done? Is there some sort of best practice?

(I know that in some cases it would be possible to split that one job into multiple jobs that each run a single command, passing the output as an artifact to the next job, but that can quickly become inefficient and hard to read.)

**Edit**: Moved some of the ideas I had into the answer.

Comment: It's pretty common to build and maintain your own image. You even have a CI server there to do it.

Comment: That is true and you are totally right about that, but if you want to always use the latest versions for most of the tools and you are using a lot of tools within one image, you will end up having to do a lot of manual maintenance work (for example because new dependencies are required for later versions or dependencies are conflicting).

Comment: [This page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/index.html) is likely very relevant for you... particularly: [What services are not for](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/index.html#what-services-are-not-for) and [Shared /builds directory](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/index.html#shared-builds-directory)

Comment: @Attie Thank you, that is very valuable information!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a complex workaround that covers most of the basics. If you add this to the top of your `.gitlab-ci.yml`, you can run commands in the context of any service:

```yaml
.remote_exec_server: &remote_exec_server
  - "sh"
  - "-c"
  - |
    mkdir -p "$CI_PROJECT_DIR" && cd "$CI_PROJECT_DIR"
    while true; do
      nc -l -p 83 -e sh -c '{
        IFS="|" read -r stdin_base64 cmd_base64
        stdout_file=$(mktemp)
        stderr_file=$(mktemp)
        echo -n "$stdin_base64" | base64 -d | sh -c "$(echo "$cmd_base64" | base64 -d)" > $stdout_file 2> $stderr_file
        echo "${?}|$(cat $stdout_file | base64 -w 0)|$(cat $stderr_file | base64 -w 0)"
        rm -f $stdout_file $stderr_file
      }'
    done

.remote_exec_client: &remote_exec_client |
  # Usage: svc_run SERVICE_NAME COMMAND [COMMAND_PARAMS]... # (Supports stdin, stdout, stderr and exit code)
  svc_run() {
    local stdin_base64=$(base64 -w 0)
    local host="$1"; shift
    local cmd_base64="$(echo "$*" | base64 -w 0)"
    echo "${stdin_base64}|${cmd_base64}" | nc $host 83 | {
      IFS='|' read -r exit_code stdout_base64 stderr_base64
      echo "$stdout_base64" | base64 -d
      echo "$stderr_base64" | base64 -d 1>&2
      return $exit_code
    }
    return $?
  }
```

Data is shared via the `/builds` directory automatically. (Thanks to @Attie for pointing that out.)

Now you can create jobs that can access any of the services. Here is a proof of concept demonstrating the use of python, nodejs and java from the same job:
(Note the use of `command: *remote_exec_server` on every service.)

```yaml
variables:
    CI_DEBUG_SERVICES: "true" # Show services output in GitLab CI log

before_script:
  - *remote_exec_client

helloworld:
  image: alpine:3.17.3
  services:
    - name: node:18.16.0-alpine3.17
      alias: node
      command: *remote_exec_server
    - name: python:3.11.3-alpine3.17
      alias: python
      command: *remote_exec_server
    - name: amazoncorretto:8-alpine3.17-full
      alias: jdk
      command: *remote_exec_server
  script:
    # Python test
    - svc_run python python --version
    - echo 'print("Hello, world from python!")' | svc_run python python

    # Java test
    - svc_run jdk java -version
    - echo "public class HelloWorld {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(\"Hello, World from Java!\");
        }
      }" > HelloWorld.java
    - svc_run jdk "javac HelloWorld.java && java HelloWorld" # compile and execute a java program from the given source file

    # NodeJS test
    - svc_run node node -v
    - svc_run node npm -v
    - echo 'console.log("Hello, world from nodejs!")' | svc_run node node

    # Advanced NodeJS test
    - echo '{"scripts":{"test":"mocha test.js"},"devDependencies":{"mocha":"^10.2.0"}}' > package.json
    - echo "const assert = require('assert');
      describe('My Test Suite', () => {
        it('should pass the test', () => {
          assert.strictEqual(2 + 2, 4);
        });
      });" > test.js
    - svc_run node npm install
    - svc_run node npm run test
```

**Limitations**

- One disadvantage (due to my limited shell scripting knowledge) is that `stdin` and `stdout`/`stderr` aren't streamed in real time, meaning a long running command will not produce any output, until it completely finished execution.
- The remote execution server/client relies on `netcat` (`nc`) which unfortunately isn't preinstalled in all docker images. I've only tested it with alpine-based images and that seems to work fine so far. One way to work around that might be to copy a statically built version of `nc` into the builds directory in the `before_script` and tell the server to wait for it to exist.

Please note that GitLab CI services are not officially meant to be used that way.